# jQuery Validation of Select Options

Tags: jquery, validation, html-select

I am running into some issues when trying to validate my form.

User must choose "header", "logo" and a value for each. Right now it wont validate even though I have chosen them all.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rZshJ/13/

Javascript:

```
$().ready(function(){

$('.test').hide();


$(".header, .logo").on("click",function(){

var relatedSelect2 = $(this).parent('.parent').children('.test');
$('.test').hide();
$('.parent').each(function(index){
      $(this).children('input:checked').parent('.parent').children('.test').show();
});
relatedSelect2.show();

});

jQuery('#submit').click(function(event){


if( $("input[name='header']:checked").length > 0 && $("input[name='logo']:checked").length > 0 && $('#image_option > option:selected').length != 0 ) {
    alert('Updated!');
} 
else  if( $("input[name='header']:checked").length == 0 && $("input[name='logo']:checked").length == 0 && $('#image_option > option:selected').length == 0 ) {
    alert('Please select a header and logo and template for each');
    return false;
}

else  if( $("input[name='header']:checked").length > 0 && $("input[name='logo']:checked").length == 0) {
    alert('Please select a logo');
    return false;
}
else  if( $("input[name='header']:checked").length == 0 && $("input[name='logo']:checked").length > 0) {
    alert('Please select a header');
    return false;
}
else  if( $("input[name='header']:checked").length > 0 && $("input[name='logo']:checked").length > 0 && $('#image_option > option:selected').length == 0 ) {
    alert('Please select a template');
    return false;
}
else  if( $("input[name='header']:checked").length == 0 && $("input[name='logo']:checked").length == 0 && $('#image_option > option:selected').length != 0 ) {
    alert('Please select a header and logo');
    return false;
}


});


});
```

Comment: Please fix your HTML first. IDs have to be unique, and right now it's impossible to select something for all 3 selects, as the ones that have names have the same name.

Comment: I need it so they can only select 2 but once a header, logo and options are selected it shows an error to "select a template"

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly. You want to make sure user MUST chose "Header" , "Logo", "option". Am I right? Have you looked at jQuery Validation http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Yes, the only problem I am having is that the first select dropdown has to be chosen for the form to submit, but I need the form to except any header and logo as long as they both have options chosen for them.